# access property of instance with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have Unity injection implemented on constructors. I have the follow:

```
interface IA
{
    DoSomething();
}

class A : IA
{
    private List<MyType> List;
    public A(List<MyType> list) 
    {
        this.List = list;
    }

    DoSomething()
    {
       // do something with this.List
    }
}
interface IB
{
    List<MyType> GetList();
}
class B : IB
{
    public List<MyType> GetList() { }
}

class C
{
    private A MyA;
    public C(IB b)
    {
        this.MyA = new A(b.GetList());
    }

    public DoSomethingInA()
    {
        this.MyA.DoSomething(); 
    }
}
```

I want to remove the "new A()" in constructor of class C and use injection of IA but I dont know how to register A of type IA receiving in constructor a property of an instance and not an instance itself.

I can't change implementation of A !! a List<> should be received in constructor.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of class `C` does too much; [injector constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). So instead of calling `GetList` during construction of the object graph, postpone this till a later moment and just inject `IB` in both `A` and `C` as follows:

```cs
class A : IA
{
    private IB b;
    public A(IB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    DoSomething() {
        var list = this.b.GetList();
       // do something with this.List
    }
}

class C
{
    private IB b;
    public C(IB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

This simplifies your registration, your code, and allows you [compose object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

**UPDATE**

In case the type is out of your control, you should consider it 3rd party type. In general, you should be careful in letting such type be auto-wired by the container, since the people that maintain that type might add new constructors to that type, which might break your DI registration (more info [here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Framework-types)).

So instead of letting the container auto-wire that type, register a lambda expression that creates the instance of that 3rd party type. For instance:

```
container.Register<IA>(new InjectionFactory(c => new A(c.Resolve<IB>().GetList())));
```

Do note however, that in this case you're still doing too much during the building of the object graph, and (depending on what `GetList` does under the covers) that might make it harder to verify the correctness of the graph.

So because you are working with a 3rd party type that depends on some runtime types during its construction, you might want to consider postponing the creation of that type. If you create a proxy class for `IA`, you will be able to delay the creation of `A` without the application to know anything about it. That proxy might look something like this:

```
class DelayedAProxy : IA
{
    private readonly Lazy<IA> a;
    public DelayedAProxy(Lazy<IA> a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public DoSomething() {
        this.a.Value.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And you can register it as follows:

```
container.Register<IA>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
{
    var lazy = new Lazy<IA>(() => new A(c.Resolve<IB>().GetList()));
    new DelayedAProxy(lazy);
}));
```

Here we don't register `A` directly, but `DelayedAProxy` instead and that proxy will only cause `A` to be created when `DoSomething` is executed for the first time, which will be after the complete object graph is created.

Alternatively, your proxy could also just depend on `IB` and create the lazy internally. That would like this:

```
class DelayedAProxy : IA
{
    private readonly Lazy<IA> a;
    public DelayedAProxy(IB b) {
        this.a = new Lazy<IA>(() => new A(b.GetList()));
    }

    public DoSomething() {
        this.a.Value.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Advantage of this is that the registration of the `DelayedAProxy` becomes much easier:

```
container.RegisterType<IA, DelayedAProxy>();
```

Although it looks like in this case the `DelayedAProxy` constructor is doing again a lot, in fact it just creates the Lazy with the delegate. `GetList` is only called after the construction of the proxy.

Comment: logic in constructor was for sample only, the real logic is outside. and I can't change class A, it receive only a List<> and have no reference to IB, can't add it...

Comment: @user810917: Please update your question and show us what's really going on. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user810917: btw. Calling `b.GetList()` can be considered logic as well. Injecting `IB` solves the problem effectively and elegantly.

Comment: code edited, now no logic on constructor, but dont change the subject in question

Comment: @user810917: I'm sorry, my answer stays the same: change your design.

Comment: class A can't be changed, can't inject IB on A() constructor. class A is outside my code...

Comment: @user810917: In that case, register a lambda for it, since you should not auto-wire 'framework' types.

Comment: actually is not a framework type but a class in an assembly from another project. by the way, I dont see how to register lamda, can you hint me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the design and injecting dependency using a method and not a constructor, something like:

```
interface IA
{
    Initialize(List<something> list);
    DoSomething();
}

class C
{
    private IA MyA;
    public C(IB b, IA a)
    {
        this.MyA = a;
        this.MyA.Initialize(b.GetList()); 
    }

    public DoSomethingInA()
    {
        this.MyA.DoSomething(); 
    }
}
```

Initialization is done in constructor to less impact the current code calling DoSomething(), could be also possible something that:

```
    public DoSomethingInA()
    {
        this.MyA.DoSomething(b.GetList()); 
    }
```

but as I said, it impacts much more the existing code.